# I can't seem to resolve error for valueForUndefinedKey:]: whereto class is not key value coding-compliant

Tags: swift, macos, core-data

The error I can't resolve is ... valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key managedObjectContext

Here's the code snippet in question (I think) ...

class TripSplitViewController: NSSplitViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var tripsArrayController: NSArrayController!

var managedObjectContext = (NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

I am using Swift 4 and Xcode 9.4 (macOS app) along with Core Data accessing a SQLite data base.  I have also created 3 data models with relationships defined between each.  I have also create a Split View Controller and am trying to establish my ManagedObjectContext.

One think I have done is check my binds and outlets connections and all look clean and connected correctly.

I am pretty new to Swift and Xcode and this is the first issue I have encountered that all the post on stack responses have not worked in my application.

And one final thing, app was working fine with Core Data until I added the Array Controller to a Split View Controller, the outlet and its connection and the var declaration for the managedObjectContext.

Please, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What class is saying that? Is it really `TripSplitViewController`?

Comment: Did you bind `managedObjectContext` of the array controller to `managedObjectContext` of the view controller? See [Using Key-Value Observing in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key_value_observing_in_swift).

Comment: larme - here's the full error I get ...*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<VacationPlanner.TripSplitViewController 0x6000001034e0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key managedObjectContext.

Answer (score 2):

From [Using Key-Value Observing in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key_value_observing_in_swift):

> Mark properties that you want to observe through key-value observing with both the @objc attribute and the dynamic modifier.

Cocoa Bindings uses KVO. Change

```
 var managedObjectContext = (NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

to

```
 @objc dynamic var managedObjectContext = (NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

Comment: willeke -  I correct the line using the @objc line and it works great!  Thanks for the help.